# Wordpress submit a form, update link with form input and go to that link & link is "#"?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

This code is a form that results in a link being created with variable `$ui.`

```
                        <form method="post" name="form" onsubmit="#">
                         Name search:
                        <input id="ui" type="text" name="ui" />
                        <input type="submit" class="Submit" value="submit" />
                        </form>
```

Then the variable $ui is used to set the value of the data-filter attribute. When you click the link (after the form submits) it goes to "#" which performs a sorting/listing function and reloads the page without refreshing.

```
                  <?php if(isset($_POST["ui"]))
                        {
                            $ui = $_POST["ui"];

                        }

                        $Filterclass = strtoupper(str_replace(" ", "-", $ui));

                        ?>

                       <a href="#" id="gallery_filter"
                       data-filter=".<?php echo $Filterclass; ?>">
                       <?php echo strtoupper($ui); ?></a>
```

Right now, the form submits and then the link is created, then you can click on it.

It works as-is, but I'd like to have the 'submit' button just open that link, the one with newly updated data-filter attribute.

I would ask this is Wordpress.exchange but I think is too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the whole process but modify your existing code as below(assuming jquery is already loaded)

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["ui"]))
                    {
                        $ui = $_POST["ui"];

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
       jQuery("#gallery_filter").click();
    });
</script>';
                    }

                    $Filterclass = strtoupper(str_replace(" ", "-", $ui));

                    ?>

                   <a href="#" id="gallery_filter"
                   data-filter=".<?php echo $Filterclass; ?>">
                   <?php echo strtoupper($ui); ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks Yamu. I see the logic here but it doesn't seem to work. I think that 'gallery-filter' might be meaningless because I change it to some other name and the form works the same.

Comment: There is a div that wraps around this entire section with an ID="bank_filters_" which must be doing the work. But I think all I need to do is somehow load that <a> tag, instead of echoing it or outputting it. Ordinarily I would simply load the link by the href, but as you can see it's "#", I think I'm just missing references on how to load a link by tag. I should probably ask a completely different question. Thanks for you help, however, I did not know you could echo scripts in that way.